# What does "penny roll" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, american-english

In the self help book 'Pushing to the front' by Orison Swett Marden, under chapter 30 (Self Help) it is said:

> Franklin was but a poor printer's boy, whose highest luxury at one time was only a penny roll, eaten in the streets of Philadelphia.

Does it mean something like "he bought a cheap sandwich or candy from a corner of the street"?

Comment: maybe or a *bread* roll that cost (then) one penny.

Comment: I'll note that, in the 50s in the US, **Tootsie Roll** candies were often sold by the piece, and, as I recall, the smallest ones could be purchased for $0.01 (one penny).  I don't doubt that some people called these "penny rolls".  (But I do recall reading in Franklin's writings that he, as a child, would buy two "penny rolls" of bread and put one under each arm as he walked the streets.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A penny roll is a bread roll (small round loaf of bread) that cost one penny (1¢)

The intention of the paragraph is to emphasise how poor Franklin was.

Answer (score 5):

I assume this passage is about Benjamin Franklin. In his time, you could buy [bread for a single penny](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penny_bun). In fact, it may be talking about this part from the [Works of the Late Doctor Benjamin Franklin (1793)](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Works_of_the_Late_Doctor_Benjamin_Franklin_(1793).djvu/42):

> I desired him to let me have three penny-worth of bread of some kind or other. He gave me three large rolls.

Comment: (In fact, that anecdote is how in his native Boston they had something called a "threepenny loaf", and, not knowing that the prices were lower in Philadelphia, he bought almost more bread than he could carry!)